# declaring javascript variables inline on a dropdown, for use elsewhere

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, inline

Is there a way to declare a variable in JavaScript in line when an element of this `dropdown` is clicked, to be displayed elsewhere on the page?

example:

```
var blood = 'A';
```

where does this need to go? Or is there a better way to do this?

The result of the selection will appear at the end of the page as a response feedback.

#### HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Blood Type</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">A+</a>
   <a href="#">A-</a>
   <a href="#">B+</a>
   <a href="#">B-</a>
   <a href="#">B+</a>
   <a href="#">AB+</a>
   <a href="#">AB-</a>
   <a href="#">0+</a>
   <a href="#">0-</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: yes, there is a way. It needs to go in a script block. So what have you found in your research to try? What was the result of that trial? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the container, which checks the clicked `a`'s text:

```js
const results = document.querySelector('#results');
document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const a = event.target;
  if (a.tagName !== 'A') return;
  const bloodTypeSelected = a.textContent;
  results.textContent = 'You chose: ' + bloodTypeSelected;
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Blood Type</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">A+</a>
    <a href="#">A-</a>
    <a href="#">B+</a>
    <a href="#">B-</a>
    <a href="#">B+</a>
    <a href="#">AB+</a>
    <a href="#">AB-</a>
    <a href="#">0+</a>
    <a href="#">0-</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Don't try to do it inline - inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead.